# limit of a function which is defined for rational and irrational points on real line explicitly

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$ \text{Let }f(x)=x ,x\in \mathbb{Q}\\ \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }=2-x , x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$$
show that (i) $\lim_{x\to1}f(x) =1$  , (ii)$\lim_{x\to c}f(x) \text {does not exist, if }c\neq 1$

Comment: You can use `\quad` or `\ \ `  for white-spacing. But, actually, `\begin{align} \end{align}` is what you wanted.